# How sort the three first rows of a groupby and agg (sum and count) ? Python - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this df :

```
                            sum     count
priority       alias        
120            CI0          7.13    903
               CI1          2.57    1
               CI2          2.27    1
               CI3          1.34    81
               CI4          2.21    1
               CI5          5.34    14
123            G1           2.95    3
               G2           4.67    12
               M1           5.21    2
126            M2           4.14    279
               A1           1.86    8
```

I would like to extract the three first alias's rows of each priority.

The result must be :

```
                            sum     count
priority       alias        
120            CI0          7.13    903
               CI1          2.57    1
               CI2          2.27    1
123            G1           2.95    3
               G2           4.67    12
               M1           5.21    2
126            M2           4.14    279
               A1           1.86    8
```

I tried to place `head(3)` in my code but it doesn't work, my currently code:

```
df = df.groupby(['priority', 'alias'])['duration'].agg(['sum','count'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `groupby().head()`

```
df.groupby('priority').head(3)


     priority alias   sum  count
0        120   CI0  7.13    903
1        120   CI1  2.57      1
2        120   CI2  2.27      1
6        123    G1  2.95      3
7        123    G2  4.67     12
8        123    M1  5.21      2
9        126    M2  4.14    279
10       126    A1  1.86      8
```

Comment: when we did the hardest and we can't do the easiest ... It was enough to do it separately. Thanks